# Using django channels with websockets (React + django), I am getting an error when sending message from inside useEffect in react

Tags: reactjs, django, websocket

The error is that websocket is still in connection phase. This is the error message in console

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at websocket__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.client.onmessage
```

This is the code inside use effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
websocket.onmessage = (e) => {
        const dataReceived = JSON.parse(e.data)
}
if(dataReceived['Message'] == 'Hello'){

               websocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                State: 'Message Hello Received',
                toSendBack: 'Hi',
              }))
}
},[]}
```

As you can see i am using if condition to check that if the message sent from the backend is 'Hello' I am sending a message from inside use effect in react which says 'hi'.

Comment: Maybe wait for open state? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#sending_data_to_the_server. Also don't forget to close websocket.

Comment: @bysEcode did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

this is the approach that i used befor:

```
const [chatSocket, setChatSocket] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
        if (!chatSocket) {
            newChatSocket()
        }
}, [])

const newChatSocket = () => {
    setChatSocket(new WebSocket(
        'websocket_url'
    ))
}

if (chatSocket) {
    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
        // do something
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function (e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };
}
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, I will try it and will tell if it works in a minute

Comment: It didn't work because I am receiving messages on connection so it gave me an error after reloading Thx anyways though